# How to only get the first instance of a particular column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query, and I sorted my data on first a unique identifier for a person, then the date created...

So for each new instance a unique id I only want that row.. the rest can be thrown away. I tried a nested select statement:

```
 SELECT d.full_name as "Name",
        d.id as "Unique Identifier",
        s.service_name as "service",
        t.create_date as "date created"
        from 
        data d,
        transaction t,
        system s
        where
         ...
        s.system = 251 
        order by d.id, t.create_date desc
```

and I get an error each time as I assume I am not using group by correctly. What is the best way to get only the first instance of a new unique identifier and throw the rest away?

Edit:

Here is some sample data:

```
Name         Unique Identifier      service          date created

john doe     1                      eca              1/14/2008 
john doe     1                      ecb              1/10/2008 
john doe     1                      eca              11/12/2007
henry ford   2                      ford1            06/07/2010
henry ford   2                      ford2            08/09/2009
jack johnson 4                      burgers1         11/01/2013
jack johnson 4                      burgers2         09/06/2007
```

so all I want is these lines to print:

```
john doe     1                      eca              1/14/2008 
henry ford   2                      ford1            06/07/2010
jack johnson 4                      burgers1         11/01/2013
```

which are the most recent requests per each person.. but each line still may have different data.

Comment: Can you provide a couple rows of sample data from the table and your expected result based on that sample?

Comment: I added some sample data brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>If I'm reading your question correct I believe you want the first row for every unique id?</del>

**EDIT** : when you added the sample data it became much easier to understand what you want.

As you haven't added the database structure my query does only involves one table, not three as your sample query, because I can't tell how they are joined. It should be easy to adapt the query to the proper tables and joins though.

The following query should do it:

```
SELECT 
  t1.full_name AS "Name",
  t1.id AS "Unique Identifier",
  t1.service_name AS "Service",
  t1.create_date AS "Date created"
FROM table1 t1,
  (SELECT id, MAX(create_date) AS last_date
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id) t2
   WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.create_date = t2.last_date
ORDER BY t1.id
```

See [this sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ebc7/1) (Oracle 11g R2) for an example.

Output from the query above:

```
|         NAME | UNIQUE IDENTIFIER |  SERVICE |                    DATE CREATED |
|--------------|-------------------|----------|---------------------------------|
|     john doe |                 1 |      eca |  January, 14 2008 01:00:00+0000 |
|   henry ford |                 2 |    ford1 |     June, 07 2010 02:00:00+0000 |
| jack johnson |                 4 | burgers1 | November, 01 2013 01:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. This seemed to get complicated real quick when trying to sort on the requirements. My experience with SQL was limited but I just needed to be shown how to do something like that, and the max()  grouped by makes a lot more sense. Although, when I use the max() on the date it seems to have a lot of dates with that are the same for the user. There is a queuing engine which runs and closes the tickets so this is why.. but is there a better way to get the max date? Maybe it's only comparing it up to the second

Comment: @user1794106 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The MAX(date) will return the last date, and if there are many rows with the same date does not matter.